# Fill ArrayList with colors for Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, colors

I want to create 2 ArrayList. One holding 16 colors, the other one holding 139.

I have the list with colors (both RGB as 255,126,32 and Hex as 0xFFFF2552). I want to use the ArrayList to later pick random colors from.

I've tried int[], that doesn't work. I've tried `ArrayList<Integer>` and `ArrayList<Color>`. My problem is; I don't understand how to add the colors to the ArrayLists.

Thanks!!

For now, I'm exploring this:

```
Color cBlue = new Color(0,0,255);
Color cRed = new Color(255,0,0);

ArrayList colors = new ArrayList();
colors.add(cBlue);
colors.add(cRed);
```

and so on...

I really like `int[] colors = = new int[] {4,5};` because it's only one line of code... but how do I get colors in, to later on, pick from?

or.. would it be better to store the colors in a strings.xml file and then fill the ArrayList from there? If so, how should I do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: `List<Color> list = new ArrayList<Color>();`

`list.add(cBlue);`

Should work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
int[] colors = new int[] {Color.rgb(1,1,1), Color.rgb(...)};
```

For example, but I don't think it's a good idea to decide only using "one line" argument.

```
List<Integer> coloras = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{Color.rgb(1, 1, 1), Color.rgb(...)});
```

Will also work.

You can create an arraylist in `arrays.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="colors">        
        <item>#ff0000</item>
        <item>#00ff00</item>  
        <item>#0000ff</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then use the loop to read them:

```
String[] colorsTxt = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);
List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < colorsTxt.length; i++) {
    int newColor = Color.parseColor(colorsTxt[i]);
    colors.add(newColor);
}
```

In my opinion keeping colors in the list is the most convinient solution.

To take a color from the list randomly, you do:

```
int rand = new Random().nextInt(colors.size());
Integer color = colors.get(rand);
```

Comment: And if you absolutely need to have a List structure, you can use `Arrays.AsList(...)` method

Comment: Code example is bugged trying to loop on colors.size() when colors is empty, and you're swiping information from other answers, namely mine which is the best answer :)

Comment: I fixed it just before :P, Yes @gknicker, I just improve my answer minute after minute :) Is it wrong? Your answer is good, but you weren't first.

Comment: Competing for the fastest, bestest answer :D.. That's what makes stackexchange a great resource, I guess. Experimenting with both solutions now. .. I get an error on the add statement for the List. The fist solution breaks on "The constructor Color(int, int, int) is undefined"..

Error : The method add(int, Color) in the type List<Color> is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: It's something wrong with your code then @KeesKoenen. You should use one argument which is type of Color.

Comment: I import android.graphics.Color .. could that be the problem? Do I need to change to a different Color class?

Comment: Yeah, there is no constructor Color(int, int, int) in this class. Try Color.rgb(int,int,int) instead. I fixed my answer. Sorry for this, I don't have any IDE around.

Comment: Nope.. "Color.rgb cannot be resolved to a type". I like the array.xml solution best. How would you say I fix the add(int, Color) problem? (it breaks : "The method add(int, Color) in the type List<Color> is not applicable for the arguments (int)" What does the int stand for? Is that the place in the arraylist, or something else?

Comment: My fault. It looks like you never get the object of Color class. You use int or Integer to represent color in Android.

Comment: Nope.. Still not working :( : "Cannot invoke add(int) on the array type int[]" on the colors.add line. I believe because adding an int to an Array with elements of type Integer?.. puzzled...

Comment: Should be autoboxed :( I'm addicted to IDE. Fixed finally, I believe.

Comment: Thanks man! It looks like usable code. Now, I have to pass the list to my GridViewAdapter, but that's an entirely different story ;). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would make a text file or xml file populated with the color info and have a function that reads in each line of the file using a loop, creates a Color object for each line and adds it to the array list and then goes to the next line until there are no lines left.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against using a configuration file unless you want to be able to change your colors without code changes. I suspect your colors are constant though, so the file would just add unnecessary complexity to your application.

The code sample in your question assumes `java.awt.Color` when you would actually use the utility class `android.graphics.Color` which cannot be instantiated.

Therefore I recommend the following solution as a static variable (and be careful not to modify the contents of the array later):

```
static final int[] colors16 = {
  Color.rgb(255, 0, 0),
  Color.rgb(0, 255, 0),
  Color.rgb(0, 0, 255)
};
```

Now add a static instance of Random to use for selecting random colors from the list.

```
static final Random random = new Random();
```

And then pick your color!

```
int colorIndex = random.nextInt(colors16.size());
Color color = colors16.get(colorIndex);
```

If you feel it's important to protect the contents of your list, you can make it immutable as follows, at the small expense of boxing your color `int`s into `Integer` objects.

```
static final List<Integer> colors = Collections.unmodifiableList(
  Arrays.asList(
    Integer.valueOf(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)),
    Integer.valueOf(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0)),
    Integer.valueOf(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255))
  )
);
```

Technically you can leave out the `Integer.valueOf()` conversion in the above snippet and Java will autobox the ints.

Comment: This is also a valid answer. However, I like the 'cleanliness' of the XML solution, less clutter in the code. (call me weird ;). I'm still experimenting passing the List to my Adapter, I believe both solutions pose the same problems with regards to that. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can also can use `int[] colors = new int[]{color1.getRGB(),color2.getRGB()};`
And decode using: `Color color = new Color(colors[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks like it makes sense, but you should specify the type of the ArrayList.

```
List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<Color>();
colorList.add(cBlue);
... etc
```

(The difference between declaring it as a List or an ArrayList is that List is the interface that ArrayList implements. This is a generally pretty good practice, but for your purposes it probably won't make a difference if you declare it as a List or an ArrayList).

If you want to do it in fewer lines of code, you can use an ArrayList initializer block, like this:

```
List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<Color> { new Color(...), cBlue };
```

Or with Arrays.asList, which takes in an array and returns a List.

But in general you should get used to verbosity with Java, don't try to optimize your lines of code so much as the performance of those lines.

(Sidenote: make sure you're using the correct Color class. There's android.graphics.Color and java.awt.Color, and they're totally different, incompatible types. The constructor you're using is from java.awt.Color, and with Android you're probably going to want to use android.graphics.Color).