# Android - Error with getApplicationContext

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an arraylist so then I can randomly pick a string from a list. I visited this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992120/fill-arraylist-with-colors-for-android) and on this question there was the perfect [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992120/fill-arraylist-with-colors-for-android#answer-27992171) for what I wanted to do. Although on this piece of code:

```
String[] colorsTxt = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);
    List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < colorsTxt.length; i++) {
        int newColor = Color.parseColor(colorsTxt[i]);
        colors.add(newColor);
    }
```

I can't find why getApplicationContext gives me an error, someone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using it in a ```Activity```, you can use it's own context.

Comment: You are probably not calling it from within a subclass of Context or Activity. But you need to state what the error actually is if you want useful help --that's probably why someone downvoted you.

Comment: @ErickFilho I was using it on a fragment, maybe that's because it wasn't working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you said you are using it in a fragment, you need to call `getActivity().getResources()...` to access it :).

Comment: Don't worry about it, glad I could help!