# Random Color Generator on Phone shake

Tags: android, android-studio

I have made an app that shows random color on shake. Now I tried to make it up a little bit a game. But now I am unable to handle the buttons. My main idea is, first the user need to choose the button then after shake if the color match then there is win otherwise, loose Here you can find my code. Can anyone help me with this?[This is how my app looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wUoF.jpg)

Here is my .XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/t21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#59C4C5"
        android:text="Win or Loose"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tableLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="354dp"
        android:layout_height="237dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/t"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fed766"
                android:minWidth="88dp"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="88dp"
                android:text=""
                android:background="#eec9d2"

                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="88dp"
                android:text=""
                android:background="#f07d38"

                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="88dp"
                android:text=""
                android:background="#c7243a"
               />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:background="#f485c7"
               />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff1f5d4f"

                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#c6cc56a9"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#f3227588"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#f2684ab4"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#d2e7ff"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff6f69"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#bed905"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e43afee1"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#bf30b02f"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#a8e6cf"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#d2d4dc"
                android:text="" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ea9ed0a6"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#d9ad0495"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff4e6"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#be9b7b"
                android:text="" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="Choose one of the above color"
        android:background="#8b9dc3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my .java below:

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.squareup.seismic.ShakeDetector;
import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ShakeDetector.Listener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        ShakeDetector shakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(this);
        shakeDetector.start(sensorManager);


    }

    @Override
    public void hearShake() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.t);

        int color = Color.argb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        textView.setText("Random color value is "+Integer.toHexString(color)+"\n and you choose "+color);
        findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(color);

    }
}
```

And here is one implementation that I have make in Gradle Scripts ->Build.Gradle(Module.app)->

```
dependencies { 
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:seismic:1.0.2'  ///only this line is added. 
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a fixed set of colors to randomly choose from, otherwise it would be near impossible to guess the right color. 
So for instance fill an array with colors like done in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27992171/2131277)

Then create a button for each color in the array.
Also store the chosen color in a variable so you can check if a person guessed the right color after the shake.

Comment: Thanks edwardbrosens, I will try to implement this method. But after solving my current query.